# Выборочно вывести содержимое json файла в listbox

Tags: c#, json

Я загружаю веб-страницу, которая содержит json текст и хочу, чтобы листбокс показывал некоторые поля этого json файла. Этим кодом я станицу загружаю и получаю json, но не знаю как сделать так, чтобы в Combobox'e  показывался просто список городов: London, Paris

```
  private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var json = webClient.DownloadString((My_Url));
        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject o = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
        json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(webClient.DownloadData(My_Url));


    }
}
```

Вот json-файл:

```
{ 
    "response": {
        "status": "ok",
        "data": {
            "30": {
                "title": "London",
                "Country": "Britain"
            },
            "24": {
                "title": "Paris",
                "Country": "France"
            }
        },
        "count": 2
    }}
```

Comment: Ну, для начала вопрос: вы отдаёте себе отчёт, что у вас невалидный json?

Comment: Это для простого примера, использую в коде я валидный

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправил json

Comment: @AK, ну и что, что джсон невалидный ? Будто его распарсить нельзя. Вк. например, отдают невалидный джсон и при этом хорошо себя чувствуют, и заставляют других ипользовать и парсить этот самый невалидный json. Это плохо, конечно, но всё же...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это **Linq-запрос**, который выбирает список городов из вашей структуры **JSON-данных**:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(str);

var result = json["response"]?["data"]?
               .Select(s => s.First?["title"]?.ToString())
               .ToList() ?? new List<string>();
```

Comment: Спасибо! А что нужно выводить в листбокс?  Если я вывожу result, то выводится system.collections..., если вывожу json, то выводится отлично весь список, но ведь нужны только города

Comment: Дак добавьте элементы, которые находятся в переменной `result` в `ListBox`. Вы используете Winforms или WPF?

Comment: Я Wpf использую

Comment: Если я пишу Listbox.Text = result.ToString(); то выводится не текст, а System.collections...без тустринга вообще нельзя

Comment: А что это у вас за `Listbox` такой который имеет свойство `Text `? Может это `TextBox`?

Comment: Ой, оговорка, он просто назван list. Это комбобокс, в его выпадающем списке должны быть города

Comment: Текст можно вывести так: `Listbox.Text  = string.Join(", ", result);`

Comment: Проверил на текстблоке - работает, отлично, а как вывести в список combobox?

Comment: Добавьте значение из `result` в коллекцию, к которой привязан `ComboBox`.

Comment: Ну да, там уже просто, спасибо большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста.....

Answer (score 0):

[Вот здесь](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) ты найдёшь примеры использования. Смотри раздел **SelectToken with LINQ** или **SelectToken with JSONPath**

Comment: Мне подходит with linq, но тогда вылезает исключение "значение не может быть неопределённым". Я полагаю, это он ругается на список. Json файл загружается сам по себе все ещё успешно

Comment: Значит, элемента с таким токеном или удовлетворяющего твоему условию не найдено. Остановись в отладчике, проверь - что лежит в дереве Json'а.